# FFProbe XML XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm stuck trying to use XPath and pull the variables out of this XML provided by FFProbe.
/ffprobe/streams/codec_type

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <ffprobe> 
        <streams> 
            <stream index="0" codec_name="mpeg2video" codec_long_name="MPEG-2 video"/>` 
            </stream>
        </streams>
    </ffprobe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath,

```
/ffprobe/streams/codec_type
```

selects `codec_type` elements with the specified heritage, yet your XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ffprobe> 
    <streams> 
        <stream index="0" codec_name="mpeg2video" codec_long_name="MPEG-2 video"/>` 
        </stream>
    </streams>
</ffprobe>
```

1. has no such element, and
2. is *not* well-formed since it has an extraneous `</stream>` closing tag following a self-closed `<stream/>` tag.

Comment: Well, when I see XPath related question with your answer I understand I will not be able to give better answer than your even before I start reading it :)

Comment: @Prophet:  I've seen excellent answers from you too, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I thought as much but wanted to know from more experienced users.